# Resize SVG image inside View

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, view, android-gradle-plugin

I have a FloatingActionButton with a SVG image binded to it's src property. But It doesn't view the size I need, How to resize it to show the image bigger?

Here is my drawable:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#ffffff"
    android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
```

And here is my view:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp" />
```

Comment: did you try giving width and height to FAB in your view instead of wrap_content?

Answer (score 0):

Support Vector Drawables and Animated Vector Drawables
Vector drawables allow you to replace multiple png assets with a single vector graphic, defined in XML. While previously limited to Lollipop and higher devices, both `VectorDrawable` and `AnimatedVectorDrawable` are now available through two new Support Libraries support-vector-drawable and animated-vector-drawable, respectively.

Android Studio 1.4 introduced limited support for vector `drawables` by generating pngs at build time. To disable this functionality (and gain the true advantage and space savings of this Support Library), you need to add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to your `build.gradle` file:

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+

 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

You’ll note this new attribute only exists in the version 2.0 of the Gradle Plugin. If you are using Gradle 1.5 you’ll instead use

```
// Gradle Plugin 1.5

 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```

And your xml layout add this code   `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"` .Like this code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_24dp" />
```

Helpful link  [Support Vector Drawables and Animated Vector Drawables](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)