# VectorDrawable is shown with pixels

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I created ImageView with VectorDrawable. In an android emulator all works properly, but in my phone an image is pixelated.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_circle_hello"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_circle"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: This should help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271025/vectordrawable-image-becomes-pixelated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271025/vectordrawable-image-becomes-pixelated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device version API less than 21, you must add this line to defaultConfig in Gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

And also you must use `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle"` instead of `android:src="@drawable/ic_circle"`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_circle"
```

to

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle"
```